Why reticulate package is not working in R?
I am using reticulate package in R. I am trying to import arcpy using py_run_string (Python 3.9 version). Same code is working on my desktop. What can be the reason it is not working in my laptop?
Here is my code:
install.packages("reticulate")
library(reticulate)
reticulate::conda_list()
py_run_string("import arcpy")

I am getting the following error:
Error in python_config_impl(python) : 
  Error 103 occurred running C:/Users/sadia/Scripts/python.exe: 
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  :
  running command '"C:/Users/sadia/Scripts/python.exe" "C:/Users/sadia/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/reticulate/config/config.py"' had status 103
Error in python_config_impl(python) : 
  Error 103 occurred running C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe: 
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  :
  running command '"C:/Users/sadia/OneDrive/Documents/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe" "C:/Users/sadia/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/reticulate/config/config.py"' had status 103
Error in python_config_impl(python) : 
  Error 103 occurred running C:/Users/sadia/Scripts/python.exe: 
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  running command '"C:\Users\sadia\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys; print(sys.platform)"' had status 103
2: In system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  :
  running command '"C:/Users/sadia/Scripts/python.exe" "C:/Users/sadia/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/reticulate/config/config.py"' had status 103
Error in python_config_impl(python) : 
  Error 103 occurred running C:/Users/sadia/Scripts/python.exe: 
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = TRUE,  :
  running command '"C:/Users/sadia/Scripts/python.exe" "C:/Users/sadia/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/reticulate/config/config.py"' had status 103
Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert) : 
  Evaluation error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.


A likely reason is that Python is not properly installed on your laptop, or you have an older version of Python installed.

I have Python 3.9, the same version used on the desktop.

What IDE or R editor are you using?

I am using R 4.2.2, PyCharm 2022.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-222.4459.20, built on November 17, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.5+7-b469.71 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0, GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2014M, Cores: 12

@I_O thanks for your comment. Can you clarify it? What did you mean by steer clearing OneDrive folder?

Perhaps you can try using the new Positron IDE. I have found that I am able to more easily install and run Python modules in R in that IDE

Hi @IfeanyiIdiaye, did you mean this link https://www.positronstudio.co.uk/index.php/downloads_new/

This sounds related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71774951/20513099

@Chowdhury they mean this positron.

It may be worth trying some of the troubleshooting steps discussed here: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1422
